# how do I wrap bytes into XML for to feed the XML to webservice

Tags: java, web-services, software-design

We need to implement the following solution (hope, the diagram gives a grasp of the whole picture):
[image]
there will be **Hardware Readers** (vendor-proprietary) **reading** some **stuff** and **sending** it **to ReaderAdapter** (ReaderAdapters will be installed 1 per computer). As there can be many HardwareReaders sending info to ReaderAdapters, we assume **ReaderAdapter** should be implemented as **thin client**, i.e. contain no business logic - just **wrap the stream of bytes** received from HardwareReader-s **into XML and feed to WebService**. The WebService will contain all the processing business logic.

**So my question is**: how do I wrap bytes into XML? what do you think concerning the solution in whole, perhaps someone has alternative/better suggestions?

**Thanks in advance**, any help/hints upon the point would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use Base64Encoding to generate a String from byte[] then use it build an XML string as your webservice accepts. in the webservice you can recover the byte[] from String (Base64).